# Maximizing sum of returns over multiple MDPs

Tags: optimization, markov-process, control-theory, optimal-control, dynamic-programming

Let $\triangle \mathcal{S}$ denote the set of probability distributions over a set $\mathcal{S}$. Consider an [MDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) with a set of states $\mathcal{S}$, set of actions $\mathcal{A}$, reward function $R : \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, transition function $T : \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \triangle \mathcal{S}$, and discount factor $\gamma : [0, 1)$. Let $R_\pi : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $T_\pi : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \triangle \mathcal{S}$, and $V_\pi : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the reward, transition, and value functions induced by a policy $\pi : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$, where the value function

\begin{align}
V_\pi &= R_\pi + \gamma T_\pi R_\pi + \gamma^2 T_\pi^2 R_\pi + \gamma^3 T_\pi^3 R_\pi + \dots \\
&= R_\pi + \gamma T_\pi V_\pi \\
V_\pi &= (I - \gamma T_\pi)^{-1} R_\pi
\end{align}

is the return (expected sum of discounted rewards) of that policy starting from any given state. Consider the problem of finding an optimal policy, i.e.

$$\pi^\ast \in \operatorname*{argmax}_{\pi : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}} V_\pi$$

To find such an optimal policy, one can use algorithms like value iteration, policy iteration, or linear programming. Now consider the problem of finding a policy that maximizes the *sum* of returns over a *batch* $\mathcal{I}$ of MDPs, i.e.

$$\pi^\ast \in \operatorname*{argmax}_{\pi : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}} \sum_{i : \mathcal{I}} (I - \gamma T_\pi^{(i)})^{-1} R_\pi^{(i)} $$

Has this problem been discussed in the literature? Is there an efficient algorithm for finding such an optimal policy? I tried some modifications/extensions of value iteration but they seem to converge only sometimes, at other times oscillating between a finite set of "solutions". For example, consider the algorithm that iterates
\begin{align}
Q^{(i)}(s, a) &\gets R^{(i)}(s, a) + \gamma \sum_{s' : \mathcal{S}} T^{(i)}(s, a, s') V^{(i)}(s') \\
\pi(s) &\gets \operatorname*{argmax}_{a : \mathcal{A}} \sum_{i : \mathcal{I}} Q^{(i)}(s, a) \\
V^{(i)}(s) &\gets Q^{(i)}(s, \pi(s))
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
V &: \mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
Q &: \mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
\pi &: \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}
\end{align}
until convergence in $V$. Notice that $|\mathcal{I}| = 1$ yields ordinary value iteration. This algorithm seems to sometimes converge and sometimes enter a cycle in $V$.